# delete GridView row and create column programmatically

Tags: asp.net

Iam using data Bind except of data source. I want to add column and use delete function on that column for delete selected row.  I am using select option for get value of selected row.  Now I have problem on row click or row select.

Answer (score 0):

Add a delete button to the gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteRow" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" CausesValidation="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add a row command event handler to your gridview:

```
OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand"
```

Add delete logic to the command event handler:

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
    {
        //Delete the record using e.CommandArgument as the ID
        gv.DataBind() //rebind the grid so that the deleted row is gone
    }
}
```

Note: Command Name must NOT be "Delete" because that is reserved for the "automatic" delete

Comment: on click the delete button invalid post back or callback argument exception occured.

Comment: Make sure you are not binding the grid again on postback:

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }

Comment: We are going to need you to share your code so we can help you debug

Comment: i have done this.. thanks a lot sir. i stuck on another problem. kindly help me.
I am trying to open a form when a column is clicked in .rdlc report by using hyperlink. What would be the code to be written in expression for hyperlink to opening form?
actually i want open next form with hyperlink..

Comment: I cannot help you with the .rdlc so you should create a new question and tag the reportviewer. Did you get this issue figured out? if so please mark as answer